# Exclude port number in URL - Angular2

Tags: angular, webpack

I want to exclude the port number for my angular2 application in the URI, so far its http://localhost:3000/ instead of just being http://localhost/. I am using angular2 with webpack2. How would I go about doing this on development in dev-server, would I use a proxy?

-G

Answer (score 1):

A url like `http://localhost` actually has a port number, it's the default http port of 80. So you could configure your Angular app to simply use port 80 instead of port 3000.

Most projects use ports other than 80 because most web developers have a system-wide webserver that's already running on port 80 (Apache, nginx, etc).

Comment: Yes, I understand that it has a port number, I am not asking to use "no" port at all, I am simply asking how can I remove the port in the URI.

Comment: @TGarrett, that's what the answer is saying - if you set your dev server to run on port 80 instead of port 3000, then you don't have to specify a port in your URL - in the absence of a port in the url, the browser assumes the server is running on port 80

Comment: I understand that, I guess I was not clear enough, I want to maintain that port, but I want to "hide" it in the URI.

Comment: Then whatever is listening on port 80 will have to do that hiding for you. Look into either Apache's [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass), or nginx's [proxy_pass](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass). Or any other proxy software: but yes, you're going to want a proxy for this.